# SQL - Turn one date column into FromDate & ToDate columns

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am new to SQL and mostly use the data from Queries in Power BI.

I  to split my date column into two date columns in SQL based on Status. (on The days that status was changed)

I have an SQL query which gives me below straightforward results

```
SERIAL NO         ENTITY_CODE COMPANY_NAME      STATUS       TRANSACTION_DATE
AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL FRANCIS     MADICAL           Activation      27-04-12 18:30
AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL DEADPOOL    FAST TRANSPORT    Disconnection   27-12-14 15:01
12345678901       DEADPOOL    FAST TRANSPORT    Activation      27-04-12 18:30
12345678901       DEADPOOL    FAST TRANSPORT    Disconnection   17-01-16 16:35
PQ:RS:TU:VW:XY:ZA DEADPOOL    FAST TRANSPORT    Activation      27-04-12 18:31
PQ:RS:TU:VW:XY:ZA DEADPOOL    FAST TRANSPORT    Disconnection   02-12-13 13:26
78901234567       BANDHU      BANDHU CABS       Activation      27-04-12 19:12
78901234567       BANDHU      BANDHU CABS       Disconnection   27-10-13 19:42
78901234567       DEADPOOL    FAST TRANSPORT    Reconnection    25-02-14 13:53
78901234567       DEADPOOL    FAST TRANSPORT    Disconnection   08-04-16 17:14
```

This one is simple 'select' query with some conditions and 'Order By'.

In order to find, how many days this Serial No was Active and DisConnected, I need this data in below-mentioned format. Which I need for Power BI.

```
SERIAL NO           ENTITY_CODE  COMPANY_NAME   STATUS          FromDate      ToDATE
AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL   FRANCIS      MADICAL        Activation      27-04-12 18:30  27-12-14 15:01
AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL   DEADPOOL     FAST TRANSPORT Disconnection   27-12-14 15:01  TODAY'S DATE
12345678901         DEADPOOL     FAST TRANSPORT Activation      27-04-12 18:30  17-01-16 16:35
12345678901         DEADPOOL     FAST TRANSPORT Disconnection   17-01-16 16:35  TODAY'S DATE
PQ:RS:TU:VW:XY:ZA   DEADPOOL     FAST TRANSPORT Activation      27-04-12 18:31  02-12-13 13:26
PQ:RS:TU:VW:XY:ZA   DEADPOOL     FAST TRANSPORT Disconnection   02-12-13 13:26  TODAY'S DATE
78901234567         BANDHU       BANDHU CABS    Activation      27-04-12 19:12  27-10-13 19:42
78901234567         BANDHU       BANDHU CABS    Disconnection   27-10-13 19:42  25-02-14 13:53
78901234567         DEADPOOL     FAST TRANSPORT Reconnection    25-02-14 13:53  08-04-16 17:14
78901234567         DEADPOOL     FAST TRANSPORT Disconnection   08-04-16 17:14  TODAY'S DATE
```

Please note 'Today's Date' in ToDate Column.
This data will ultimately give me Status of every Serial No on Every day of that Number's Life.

I need to divide  'Transaction History' based on every transaction date so that I will be able to find out that certain Serial Number was active from  date1 to date2, and then disconnected from date 2 to date 3, and so on

Can someone help?

Comment: Is TRANSACTION_DATE a datetime datatype or are you taking in values as char, varchar, etc?

Comment: It is Date-Time, there will be Today's Date-Time at the respective cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  
    SERIAL NO
        ,ENTITY_CODE COMPANY_NAME
        ,STATUS
        ,TRANSACTION_DATE
    ,CASE STATUS
        WHEN 'Activation' THEN <WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO HAPPEN>
        WHEN 'Disconnection' THEN <WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO HAPPEN>
        WHEN 'Reconnection' THEN <WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO HAPPEN>
        ELSE <WHAT EVER YOU WANT TO HAPPEN> 
        END as ToDATE
FROM 
    <Table Name>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I failed to explain. I need to divide this transaction History on  every transaction, so that I will be able to find out that this number was active from this date1 to date 2, and then disconnected from date 2 to date 3, and so on

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `FromDate` is the same as the `TransactionDate` and the `ToDate` is the next `TransactionDate` with the same serial number.

You should be able to just create a calculated column with DAX inside Power BI to get your `ToDate`. Something like the following where `Status` is the name of your table.

```
ToDate =
    VAR EndDate = MINX(
                      FILTER('Status',
                          'Status'[Serial No] = EARLIER('Status'[Serial No]) &&
                          'Status'[TransactionDate] > EARLIER('Status'[TransactionDate])),
                      'Status'[TransactionDate])
    RETURN IF(ISBLANK(EndDate), TODAY(), EndDate)
```

Another version using `CALCULATE` instead of `MINX`:

```
ToDate = 
    VAR EndDate = CALCULATE(
                      MIN('Status'[TransactionDate]),
                      ALL('Status'),
                      'Status'[Serial No] = EARLIER('Status'[Serial No]),
                      'Status'[TransactionDate] > EARLIER('Status'[TransactionDate]))
    RETURN IF(ISBLANK(EndDate),TODAY(),EndDate)
```

Comment: Mr. Olson... You are a life saver. It worked wonderfully. Thank you very much.

Comment: I need to use a custom column after getting the ToDate Column. is there some way, I could get this ToDate Column using Custom Column (via edit query)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to select the min transaction date that is greater than the current transaction date and that has the same Serial No. If there is no match (returns NULL in this example) then return today's date.

I've used a datetime datatype, but it appears the example code selected a varchar or char. I'm assuming you're using the correct datatype.

If you have SQL Server Management Studio you can try this full example:

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE ([SERIAL NO] varchar(100), ENTITY_CODE varchar(100), COMPANY_NAME varchar(100), [STATUS] varchar(100), TRANSACTION_DATE smalldatetime)
INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES
 ('AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL', 'FRANCIS',  'MADICAL',        'Activation',    '2012-04-27 18:30:00')
,('AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL', 'DEADPOOL', 'FAST TRANSPORT', 'Disconnection', '2014-12-27 15:01:00')
,('12345678901',       'DEADPOOL', 'FAST TRANSPORT', 'Activation',    '2012-04-27 18:30:00')
,('12345678901',       'DEADPOOL', 'FAST TRANSPORT', 'Disconnection', '2016-01-17 16:35:00')
,('PQ:RS:TU:VW:XY:ZA', 'DEADPOOL', 'FAST TRANSPORT', 'Activation',    '2012-04-27 18:31:00')
,('PQ:RS:TU:VW:XY:ZA', 'DEADPOOL', 'FAST TRANSPORT', 'Disconnection', '2013-12-02 13:26:00')
,('78901234567',       'BANDHU',   'BANDHU CABS',    'Activation',    '2012-04-27 19:12:00')
,('78901234567',       'BANDHU',   'BANDHU CABS',    'Disconnection', '2013-10-27 19:42:00')
,('78901234567',       'DEADPOOL', 'FAST TRANSPORT', 'Reconnection',  '2014-02-25 13:53:00')
,('78901234567',       'DEADPOOL', 'FAST TRANSPORT', 'Disconnection', '2016-04-08 17:14:00')

SELECT M1.[SERIAL NO], M1.ENTITY_CODE, M1.COMPANY_NAME, M1.[STATUS], M1.TRANSACTION_DATE AS FromDate
      ,COALESCE(
       (SELECT MIN(TRANSACTION_DATE)
          FROM @mytable M2
         WHERE M2.[SERIAL NO] = M1.[SERIAL NO]
           AND M2.TRANSACTION_DATE > M1.TRANSACTION_DATE
       ) 
               , getDate()
               ) AS ToDATE
  FROM @mytable M1
```